# Application internal design VS Web application design

Tags: design, web-applications, applications

I come from the web application development and I try to make a small desktop application. I am looking for a good way to build the skeleton of my desktop application.

From the web design, the skeleton is mainly handled by the web browser combined with the web server which manage application states (each page could be compared to a state) which in some way "wrap" the whole application and give you access to the basic informations like the `post` and `get` variables (and many others). Finally you can wrap the whole web application in a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design.

I am wondering how I can do the same (or something similiar) in a desktop application? How can (or should) I properly wrap my application? Should I go with a state machine design combined with a MVC or is there something better?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most desktop applications are event driven, so learn that paradigm.  Most higher level RAD-style IDE's do that for you automatically.